# Write CMS signature to readable file

Tags: java, arrays, cryptography, digital-signature

I generated a `CMSSignedData` object and I want to save it in a human readable format to file.

I got now:

```
saveSigToFile(CMSSignedData sigData) throws Exception {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(getFileName() + _sig));
        try (ASN1InputStream asn1 = new ASN1InputStream(sigData.getEncoded())) {
            DEROutputStream dos = new DEROutputStream(out);
            dos.writeObject(asn1.readObject());
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            asn1.close();
        }
    }
```

But where can I tell the function to write it to the file "test.sig"?

Comment: Use a FileOutputStream instread of a ByteArrayOutputStream

Comment: writes out a file but it is not good formatted. Looks strange. Do you know how to format it the right way?

Comment: What is the "right way" for a binary file?

Comment: I mean the right way for a signature.

Comment: Note that I didn't see this question because 1. the [tag:cryptography] tag was missing and 2. [tag:signature] is for *method* signatures, you should have used [tag:digital-signature].

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for PEM. PEM consists of a header line, a footer line and base64 encoding in between. The base64 encoding provides an ASCII armor, which means the signature can be put into text messages. PEM is the default format for the OpenSSL command line. I would still not call it *human readable* though.

---

In Bouncy Castle you can use the [`JcaPEMWriter` class](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.3/org/bouncycastle/openssl/jcajce/JcaPEMWriter.html) to convert from ASN.1 objects to PEM:

```
ContentInfo cmsSignedDataAsASN1 = cmsSignedData.toASN1Structure();
try (JcaPEMWriter writer = new JcaPEMWriter(new FileWriter("test.sig"))) {
    writer.writeObject(cmsSignedDataAsASN1);
}
```

which produces a result similar to this:

```
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----
```

---

If you want to take a look at the contents you may use e.g. `openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in "test.sig"` or `openssl asn1parse -in "test.sig"` if it already has been PEM encoded.

The result is below:

```
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=inf  cons: SEQUENCE          
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :pkcs7-signedData
   13:d=1  hl=2 l=inf  cons: cont [ 0 ]        
   15:d=2  hl=2 l=inf  cons: SEQUENCE          
   17:d=3  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :01
   20:d=3  hl=2 l=  11 cons: SET               
   22:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 cons: SEQUENCE          
   24:d=5  hl=2 l=   5 prim: OBJECT            :sha1
   31:d=5  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
   33:d=3  hl=2 l=inf  cons: SEQUENCE          
   35:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :pkcs7-data
   46:d=4  hl=2 l=   0 prim: EOC               
   48:d=3  hl=2 l=inf  cons: cont [ 0 ]        
   50:d=4  hl=4 l= 500 cons: SEQUENCE          
   54:d=5  hl=4 l= 317 cons: SEQUENCE          
   58:d=6  hl=2 l=   3 cons: cont [ 0 ]        
   60:d=7  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :02
   63:d=6  hl=2 l=   6 prim: INTEGER           :015C4F78370C
   71:d=6  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
   73:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha256WithRSAEncryption
   84:d=7  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
   86:d=6  hl=2 l=  19 cons: SEQUENCE          
   88:d=7  hl=2 l=  17 cons: SET               
   90:d=8  hl=2 l=  15 cons: SEQUENCE          
   92:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName
   97:d=9  hl=2 l=   8 prim: UTF8STRING        :owlstead
  107:d=6  hl=2 l=  30 cons: SEQUENCE          
  109:d=7  hl=2 l=  13 prim: UTCTIME           :170528143137Z
  124:d=7  hl=2 l=  13 prim: UTCTIME           :180528143137Z
  139:d=6  hl=2 l=  19 cons: SEQUENCE          
  141:d=7  hl=2 l=  17 cons: SET               
  143:d=8  hl=2 l=  15 cons: SEQUENCE          
  145:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName
  150:d=9  hl=2 l=   8 prim: UTF8STRING        :owlstead
  160:d=6  hl=3 l= 191 cons: SEQUENCE          
  163:d=7  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
  165:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
  176:d=8  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
  178:d=7  hl=3 l= 173 prim: BIT STRING        
  354:d=6  hl=2 l=  19 cons: cont [ 3 ]        
  356:d=7  hl=2 l=  17 cons: SEQUENCE          
  358:d=8  hl=2 l=  15 cons: SEQUENCE          
  360:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Basic Constraints
  365:d=9  hl=2 l=   1 prim: BOOLEAN           :255
  368:d=9  hl=2 l=   5 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:30030101FF
  375:d=5  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
  377:d=6  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha256WithRSAEncryption
  388:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
  390:d=5  hl=3 l= 161 prim: BIT STRING        
  554:d=4  hl=2 l=   0 prim: EOC               
  556:d=3  hl=3 l= 226 cons: SET               
  559:d=4  hl=3 l= 223 cons: SEQUENCE          
  562:d=5  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :01
  565:d=5  hl=2 l=  29 cons: SEQUENCE          
  567:d=6  hl=2 l=  19 cons: SEQUENCE          
  569:d=7  hl=2 l=  17 cons: SET               
  571:d=8  hl=2 l=  15 cons: SEQUENCE          
  573:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName
  578:d=9  hl=2 l=   8 prim: UTF8STRING        :owlstead
  588:d=6  hl=2 l=   6 prim: INTEGER           :015C4F78370C
  596:d=5  hl=2 l=   9 cons: SEQUENCE          
  598:d=6  hl=2 l=   5 prim: OBJECT            :sha1
  605:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
  607:d=5  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
  609:d=6  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
  620:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
  622:d=5  hl=3 l= 160 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:46D6413CFA8F8CA3581DE34E45D1C52B858DEC7AD7746D46264E4854E9AA910E0197B4A1A2F0B85984F4CF96CA47B6257CB007DF72E9D1F5AC98CA5B76D75F21E980CD4877B4E7DCCE217A09E6C0E3E18F095721837DFD04D4C1290AA6885C6B05D5ECCF9789F546781F3C1BA0A16AD7379F782FA3ACEFFBA5AC8AA5D45442146E3FFD8BF957A60D7D9E0C714F5381EAC6A72D854989C2C887A92A512451441B
  785:d=3  hl=2 l=   0 prim: EOC               
  787:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: EOC               
  789:d=1  hl=2 l=   0 prim: EOC
```

And that's as human readable as it gets I suppose (but don't store it only like this, because a computer *cannot* read this last format).